# C++ factorial program give infinity for any number greater than 2

Tags: c++, factorial, infinity

So it's 5:00 A.M. where I am and I am confused and frustrated as hell. I've created a program like this before but can't understand what is going on.

I've created a very simple factorial program and have double checked the logic, but every time I enter a number greater than 2 the program goes into a loop constantly printing out "inf". I can't see ANYTHING wrong with the program itself. :(

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    double userNumber = 0;
    double i = 1;

    cout << "This program will calculate the factorial of the number you enter.\nPlease enter your number now: ";
    cin >> userNumber;

    for ( i = 1; i < userNumber; i++ ) {
        userNumber *= i;
        cout << userNumber;
}

    cout << "\n\nThe factorial is " << userNumber << "." << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

It works for 1 and 2:

[image]

But as soon as you do 3 or greater....

[image]

I haven't created a C++ program in a while but can't for the life of me see what is wrong. Is this just a super obvious syntax error, or is my computer finally breaking down on me?

EDIT: I just changed the numbers from double to int and this is what I got:

[image]

I still don't understand why it is doing this. I don't see a problem with the for loop, or anything else...

Argh. *Smashes head into desk*

Comment: The output you show doesn't match the program in the question. ("The factorial of is ..." versus "The factorial is ..."). Please always make sure that the output you show is from the actual program code in the question. Also, please don't have screenshots of *text*. Instead copy-paste the text into the question and format it properly (use e.g. `<pre>` tags)

Comment: Never modify a loop control variable in the loop body.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
for ( i = 1; i < userNumber; i++ ) {
```

to

```
for ( i = userNumber - 1; i > 1; --i ) {
```

Note that your code changes `userNumber` in the loop body, so that the loop will only terminate if `userNumber` overflows.

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks. I still don't get why my loop wasn't working, but I'll figure that out after some sleep.

Comment: @Qwurticus you're increasing `userNumber` inside the loop. So `i < userNumber` is always `true`.

Comment: @Qwurticus - the key thing to remember is that the "while" part of a `for` loop (the `i < userNumber` here) is evaluated _every time around the loop_, not once at the beginning to set the number of loops.

Comment: I know, it was a stupid mistake on my part. Probably has to do with the fact that I started it at 5 A.M., lol. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
for ( i = 1; i < userNumber; i++ ) {
        userNumber *= i;
        cout << userNumber;
}
```

this is the problem :  let `userNumber` = 5
i=1 , `userNumber`=5
i=2 , `userNumber`=10
i=3 , `userNumber`=50 ......

and loop goes on forever .  because everytime `i<userNumber`.

Also as general advice, don't compare doubles , use `(a-b) < epsilon;` where elipson is required precision .

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using one variable both as a loop bound and as a running accumulator - `userNumber` increases every time through the loop so you will never reach it.
(The expression `i < userNumber` doesn't use the value `userNumber` had when you started looping, but always compares to the current value after each round through the loop.)

Use a separate variable for the result:

```
int factorial = 1;
for ( i = 1; i < userNumber; i++ ) {
    factorial *= i;
```